# How to build a time zone+DST transition date table

Tags: time, timezone, dst

So I am trying to build a table of cities with their offset, DST transition dates, and DST offsets. Up until this point our program has been manually updated for each of the 300+ entries every year.

I know the data is supposed to be in the tz database, but I haven't been able to find a way in the provided APIs to query transition dates, or how to query the database directly. I have tried to figure out automate pulling the data from dateandtime.com, but it seems designed to prevent that (there is even a little code comment requesting you don't).

Does anyone have any experience building this data?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices

Comment: What language was this question for?  There are lots of TZDB implementations already built.  So the answer depends heavily on language.

Comment: I believe it was Java on Suse, but I don't remember much about this instance at this point, as it's been almost four years. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running on Windows you can pull this info from the registry. And it's kept up to date by Windows update. .NET has a very useful TimeZoneInfo class that can give you all of this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx

But that is Windows only...